# JavaScript prototype-Object - how to access inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

At the moment, I try to understand the Javascript prototype object.
Following situation:

```
// new Person object
function Person () {
    this.greeth = function() {
        console.log("Good morning, " + this.name);
    };
};

// add new function to Person.prototype for inheritance
Person.prototype.sayWeight = function() {
    console.log(this.weight);
};

// create new friend object
var friend = {
    forename: "Bill",
    lastname: "Gates",
    weight: 78,
    sayhello: function() {
        console.dir("Hello " + this.forename + ' ' + this.lastname);
    }
};

// assign Person.prototype to friend.prototye (inheritance)
friend.prototype = Person;

console.dir(friend);
```

Now my question:
I assign the Person Object to my `friend.prototype` .
For my understanding, "`friend`" should have all the functions of `Person.prototype` (i.e. `sayWeight()` cause of `friend.prototype = Person;` ).
But the only function I can call is friend.sayhello. 
In my output (`console.dir(friend);`), I can see the `sayWeight()` function, but when I call it, I get an error (`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sayWeight'`)

Can you explain this behavior? Why can't I access the `sayWeight()` function?

=========================================================

Another question:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "Bill Gates";
    this.weight = 78;
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello " + this.name);
    }
}

Person.prototype.sayWeight = function() {
    console.log(this.weight);
}

var friend = new Person();
```

What is the difference between the `sayWeight` and the `sayHello` function? The `sayWeight` function is in the prototype-object of Person - okay, but what advantages do I have from prototype in this case?

Comment: I wrote [this article](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-prototype) which might help you understand the differences.

Comment: A confusing thing in javascript is that `x.prototype` is not "the prototype of x".

Comment: I have edited my answer to cover your last question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you explain this behavior? Why can't I access the sayWeight() function?

Because you can't change the prototype of an object after you create it. You are setting the prototype property, but the internal prototype reference that is used by the javascript interpreter, namely `__proto__` is still the one used in effect, and currently `__proto__` is referring to `Object.prototype`.

If you changed this line `friend.prototype = Person;` to this one `friend.__proto__ = Person.prototype;` then everything will work.

If your browser supports ES5 then you can use `Object.create()` to create objects that inherit from a given prototype, or you can use a workaround adopted from the book Javascript: The Good Parts, and twisted a little by David Flanagan in his book: Javascript The Definitive Guide:

```
// inherit() returns a newly created object that inherits properties from the
// prototype object p. It uses the ECMAScript 5 function Object.create() if
// it is defined, and otherwise falls back to an older technique.
function inherit(p) {
    if (p == null) throw TypeError(); // p must be a non-null object
    if (Object.create) // If Object.create() is defined...
        return Object.create(p); // then just use it.
    var t = typeof p; // Otherwise do some more type checking
    if (t !== "object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
    function f() {}; // Define a dummy constructor function.
    f.prototype = p; // Set its prototype property to p.
    return new f(); // Use f() to create an "heir" of p.
}
```

**NOTE** `__proto__` isn't a standardized property and shouldn't be used in production code, or as @alex noted in his comment it is on the way of standardization.

**NOTE 2:** As @thg435 mentioned in his comment, an alternative to using the `__proto__` property is using [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) which is standardized in ES6.

### EDIT TO COVER LAST QUESTION

> What is the difference between the sayWeight and the sayHello function ?

The difference is that now each new instance of `Person` *(for example `new Person()`)* will have a distinct `sayHello()` function, but a shared `sayWeight()` function.

```
var friend = new Person();
var anotherFriend = new Person();

console.log(friend.sayHello === anotherFriend.sayHello); // OUTPUTS FALSE
console.log(friend.sayWeight === anotherFriend.sayWeight); // OUTPUTS TRUE
```

> what advantages do I have from prototype in this case?

Well less memory, code reuse across all instances of person, and if you already have one or more person objects and you want to add a new method to all of them without modifying each one in turn then you can add that method to the prototype and they will all inherit from it.

Comment: Remember that __proto__ is non standarized feature, and should be not used.

Comment: @KarolSikora You are correct, I just wanted to explain what is going on underneath.

Comment: @KarolSikora It is being standardised.

Comment: You could also mention https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Comment: @thg435 Added a note about that. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`Person` doesn't inherit `Person.prototype`, only instances of `Person` do. Further, with a normal *Object* say `foo = {}`, `foo.prototype` is just a normal property. You'd either need a constructor or to create the initial object defining it as having a specific prototype.

What you actually want is

```
friend = Object.create(Person.prototype);
// or, for older browsers
friend = new Person();
// or some Object.create shim
/* which gives you
friend inherits Person.prototype
       inherits Object.prototype */
```

This sets up the prototype chain. If you want to create many friends, it may be better to set up a new *constructor* `Friend`, which has `Friend.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`. This also protects `Person.prototype` from if you want to add properties to `Friend.prototype`. Then you would have

```
(instanceof) Friend inherits Friend.prototype
                    inherits Person.prototype
                    inherits Object.prototype
```

Comment: So I have to create a new Person()-Object? Something like: `var friend = new Person();
friend = {
 forename: "Bill",
 lastname: "Gates",
 weight: 78,
 sayhello: function() {
  console.dir("Hello " + this.forename + ' ' + this.lastname);
 }
};`

Comment: @Newbie no, after creating the object you would set with `friend['forename'] = 'Bill';`, etc